# Loading li tags into ul tag using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an empty unordered list in my design. Now I want to add the following to the `ul` element:

```
<li>
  <div class="item left">
    <div class="wrap">
      <h2>Test Header1</h2>

      <p>Test Copy</p>

      <p><a class="button" href="#">Click here</a></p>
    </div>

    <img src="images/bubble.jpg" width="248" height="211" class="right" />
  </div>
</li>
```

With the `setInterval`, I want to append another `li` element/content to the `ul` element without deleting the first `li` added. How do I achieve this using jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use .append: `$('ul').append('<li>....</li>');`

Answer (score 2):

Look into .append for this, eg: `$("ul").append(li_html_here);` Just bear in mind that you'll want to specify the ul with more than just $("ul") else you'll append that li to every ul on the page (eg: add an ID).

Answer (score 1):

1. Re-write Your Code as follows

```
<li class="firstli">   
  <div class="item left">
    <div class="wrap">   
      <h2>Test Header1</h2>
      <p>Test Copy</p>
      <p><a class="button" href="#">Click here</a></p>
    </div>
    <img src="images/bubble.jpg" width="248" height="211" class="right" />
  </div>
</li>
```

2. And use the below:

```
$('ul').append($('.firstli'));
```